# jquery onclick hide/show div

Tags: jquery

I have a php file that show the friends requests, lets say there are 4 requests. I want to hide the div with the class "request_buttons" when the user clicks on accept or refuse link but the problem is that it is hiding the other 3 divs too and I want to hide only the div where the link was pressed.

My html code is:

```
<div class="request_buttons">
   <a href="#" onclick="accept(<?php echo $cerere['id']; ?>)">accept</a>
   <a href="#" onclick="refuse(<?php echo $cerere['id']; ?>)">refuse</a>
</div>
<span class="result"></span>
```

and the javascript is:

```
function accept(id)
{
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "request.php?action=accept",
       data: "id="+id,
       success: function(){
            $('.request_buttons').hide();
            $('.result').html('Request accepted');
       }
     });
}
```

LE: using the code provided by Royi Namir I came up to a sollution (by mistake).
I modified the html to this:

```
<div id="2">    
     <div class="request_buttons">
    <a href="#" onclick="accept(2)">accept</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="refuse(2)">refuse</a>
     </div>
  <div class="result"></div>            
</div>
```

and the jquery with this:

```
function accept(id)
{
t = $('#'+id);
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "request.php?action=accept",
       data: "id="+id,
       success: function(){         
       $(t,'.result').first().html('Accepted');
       }
     });
}
```

And it works, the div "request_buttons" dissapear and the message appears. I don't know how but it works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
div class="request_buttons">
   <a href="#" onclick="accept(this);">accept</a>
   <a href="#" onclick="refuse(this);">refuse</a>
</div>
```

```
function accept(obj)
{
t = $(obj);

    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "request.php?action=accept",
       data: "id="+id,
       success: function(){
            t.parent(".request_buttons").hide();
            $('.result').html('Request accepted');
       }
     });
}
```

Comment: indeed, you are right. As mugur said I must give unique ids to the divs and the use your code. It is working now, thank you very much.

Comment: Don´t forget the parameter for `id` :)

Comment: you should hide the parent of link not the link: t.parent().hide(); by that code

Comment: actually it is not working properly, it hides the correct div but the message "Request accepted" appears on the other divs too, not only on the correct div.

Comment: @PopescuMarian please clarify by some printscreen what you want

Comment: the message "Request accepted" does appears in all instances of <span class="result"></span>. The div with the id is hidden correctly, probably because it has an id, and the <span> does not or something like this.

Comment: I found by mistake a different sollutin. I edited the original post.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, replace

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "request.php?action=accept",
   data: "id="+id,
   success: function(){
        $('.request_buttons').hide();
        $('.result').html('Request accepted');
   }
 });
```

with

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "request.php?action=accept",
   context: $('#'+id),
   success: function(){
        $(this).parents('.request_buttons').hide();
        $('.result').html('Request accepted');
   }
 });
```

Comment: `this` does not refer to the clicked element in this case.

Comment: it does. see the context param in $.ajax(..)

Comment: Ah, sorry! Didn´t notice the context property. I think your post looked different when I commented it. +1 for a great solution!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jquery parent function for this. Try  `$(this).parent().hide()`